# How to force a downgrade of FlashPlayer on IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-11, flash, downgrade

I'm trying to install a lower-version of Flash Player on IE11 for debugging purposes.

But when I run the ActiveX (flashplayer_15_ax_debug.exe) installer from Adobe, I get this error:

[image]

Is there any way to bypass it so that I can test an older FP version?

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player for IE in Windows 8/8.1 is updated via Windows Update now

Why not test it on a VM where there are versions of IE that have Adobe Flash Players as "plug-ins"?

You can use this VM tool available in modern.IE site:

https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

or

test it on a different browser where Adobe Flash Players are "plug-ins"